# Can I use the same photo for a new Schengen visa application that was used in the previous visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

Schengen  Visa requires " one recent photograph (not more than 6 months old) of yourself, which should not have been used previously in the passport. The photograph should be in colour"

My previous Schengen Visa was issued in June 2019 and expired in Oct 2019. I am applying for a new visa again this week: January 2020. The photo that I am planning to use for this application is more than 6 months old and has been used previously. There has been no significant change in my appearance in the period. Am I allowed to use the same photo that I had used for the previous visa ? Is there a chance that my visa application will be rejected ?

Comment: Your photo is too old. I don't know whether your application will be rejected if you use it, but for the small cost of another photo, why take the chance?

Comment: The text (**not more than 6 months old**) is clear enough. Not sure why you are asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You photo has to be taken within the last 6 months, anything else is not accepted and you risk rejection.

It is never a good idea to send information to any goverment agency that already know is not correct.

Specially so over a 2usd photo cost